# Convert OpenStreetMap to AutoCAD/DXF/DWG with LAYERS

Tags: openstreetmap, layers, convert, autocad, dxf

Spatial Manager for AutoCAD would be the best, but it has an associated cost.
Are there any other methods? I tried using QGIS without useful results. OpenStreetMaps appears all on one layer.

How can I get maps with layers like /buildings/roads/trees/parkings/ in AutoCAD?

Comment: OpenStreetMap doesn't have layers. You will have to create them based on *tags*.

Answer (score 1):

This is Spatial Manager for AutoCAD (DEMO VERSION) 
I upload here map.osm from OpenStreetmap by exporting 
I have layers here
[image]

Comment: Maybe you know the freeware software?